# Update Cells in on Column if it Meets Criteria after Filter Another Column Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to write a code to filter data in column "A" to only "ZSFG" and "ZCNC" values. Once this criterion is met, I need to update column "C" to make sure all cells have an "X" and highlight the values that have been updated

Data:

[image: Data]

```
Sub Macro1()

    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$C$999999").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ZCNC", "ZSFG"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$C$999999").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="

   
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
     Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(, 5).Value = "X"
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

I have tried this code, but I am not getting what I am looking for.

Note: this is a large dataset, and the number of rows is never the same.

Can someone please help me?

I tried running the code above, and a few other ones. I have been able to highlight the cells that are empty but when I run the code again, the cells that get highlighted shift. also, the cells don't get fill with an X with this code

Comment: sorry, the offset I used is ( , 3). not ( , 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```vb
Sub Macro1()

Dim rg As Range
Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

With rg
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "ZCNC", "ZSFG"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
    
    With .Columns(3).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .Value = "x"
            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End With

    .Parent.ShowAllData
End With
End Sub
```

First of all I wouldn't rely on `selection`. If your table is clean you can use `CurrentRegion` to set the range to work on.

You can use `SpecialCells` but you have to "prepare" the base range beforehand.

BTW: you could achieve all that with a formula and conditional formatting as well.